# How to model many to many relationships without circles

Tags: database, relationship, geometry

**Note: Because my original question wasn't understood clearly I'm writing it completely new!**
I have two tables in my database, plus a junction/join table:
**Recipes:**

```
CREATE TABLE Recipes(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**Ingredients:**

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**IngredientsRecipes:**

```
CREATE TABLE IngredientsRecipes(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    recipeId INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ingredientId INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**My Ingredient class in php code looks like this:**

```
class Ingredient{
        private $id;
        private $name;
        private $recipes; //In which recipes this ingredient is used
}
```

**And this is my Recipes class:**

```
class Recipe{
        private $id;
        private $name;
        private $ingredients; //Ingredients used in this Recipe
}
```

Now when I want to populate the two lists I have the follwing problem:
The Recipe class has many Ingredients, and the Ingredients class has many Recipes. Each class contains contains the other, I hope this litte picture can illustrate the situation.

```
Recipe          | Ingredients   | Recipes using   |
                |used in Recipe | this Ingredient |
----------------+---------------+-----------------+

                |--Noodles------|Spaghetti
                |
Spaghetti-------|--Sauce--------|--Spaghetti   
                |
                |--Cheese-------|--Spaghetti
                                |
                                |--Mac n Cheese

                |--Macaroni-----|Mac n Cheese
                |
Mac n Cheese----|--Cheese-------|--Spaghetti
                                |            
                                |--Mac n Cheese
```

What is the prefered way of writing the model class for a many to many relationship?

Comment: What Mitch said. This is commonly called a "join table." I would name it RecipesIngredients to make its purpose explicit, however.

Comment: I know the concept of a  join table, but that's only the database site, I want to know how to represent that relation in my code

Comment: Or should I create also a class RecipeIngredient and then a list of recipeIngredient objects?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what programming language or ORM you're using?

Comment: I'm using PHP without any orm or framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done by a join or mapping table to hold the relationship between the two, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE recipe (
    recipe_id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY
    recipe_name VARCHAR (100)
    -- etc...
);

CREATE TABLE ingredient (
    ingredient_id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY
    ingredient_name VARCHAR (10),
    -- etc...
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_ingredient (
    recipe_id NUMERIC REFERENCES recipe (recipe_id),
    ingredient_id NUMERIC REFERENCES ingredient (ingredient_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, ingredient_id)
);
```